# How to add class-hierarchy based defaults without inherited attributes

Tags: python, inheritance, method-resolution-order

I have a class, let's call it `Animal`, defined in one library.

In a separate library, I want to represent these `Animal`s with colors according to their subtype. For example, a `Lion` object is red.
I want there for be a default color for any `Animal` in case a color isn't one defined for it.
I also want there be subtypes of `Animal`, such as `Feline`, that can themselves define a default color for supersedes that of generic `Animals`.

A simple way to achieve something like this would be as follows. (I use Python here to demonstrate, but I believe this to be a language-agnostic problem.)

```
class Animal:
  def __init__(self):
    self.color = Black

class Feline(Animal):
  def __init__(self):
    super.__init__()
    self.color = Blue

class Dog(Animal):
  pass  # self.color == Black

class Cat(Feline):
  pass  # self.color == Blue

class Lion(Feline):
  def __init__(self):
    super.__init__()
    self.color = Red
```

Essentially, each `Animal` will have a `color` defined by itself or the earliest ancestor that defines it.

However, I don't want the `color` of an `Animal` be a field. i.e. the representation of an `Animal` should be separate from the `Animal` itself.

So, instead, I am running something more like this:

```
# animal.py
class Animal:
  pass

class Feline(Animal):
  pass

class Dog(Animal):
  pass

class Cat(Feline):
  pass

class Lion(Feline):
  pass


# animal_colors.py
default_colors: dict[type, Color] = {
  Animal: Black,
  Feline: Blue,
  Lion: Red,
  # Notice how Cat, and Dog aren't defined here
}

def get_color(animal: Animal, lookup_table:dict[type, Color]=default_colors) -> Color:
  mro = type(animal).__mro__
  assert Animal in mro, "Non Animal class passed to get_color()"
  for t in mro:
      try:
          return lookup_table[t]
      except KeyError:
          continue
  raise RuntimeError("Animal object has no defined color")
```

This way `get_color(my_animal)` will return the desired color for an animal.

This, however, simply feels like the wrong approach to me... I don't think I should be meddling with the `__mro__` for such a simple use case.
I'm looking for better ways to tackle this problem of essentially having attributes and defaults be defined outside the class hierarchy.

Last thing I want to mention, for my case, it makes sense to have instances of `Animal` or `Feline`, which would traditionally be abstract class. i.e. objects should be able to instantiate at every level of the hierarchy.. Perhaps I could have `DefaultAnimal` and `DefaultFeline` subtypes instead, if needed.

*Bonus question: I believe this approach breaks Liskhov Substitution Principle (if a `Feline` is supposed to be `Blue`, a `Lion` shouldn't be `Red`) is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for are class attributes.

```
class Animal:
    color = Black

class Feline(Animal):
    color = Blue

class Lion(Feline):
    color = Red
```

This defines attributes that belong to the class itself, rather than to its instances. They are accessible *either* through the instance or the class. E.g.

```
Lion.color == Red # attribute on the class object
Lion().color == Red # atteibute on the instance object
```

Python does have support for abstract classes, but they are rarely used. Python is a highly pragmatic language that eschews a lot of the formality of strongly typed OO languages like Java, C# or C++. For example, it has no access modifiers, no real information hiding, no interfaces and rarely uses properties except for computed properties. Inheritance is extremely rare in day to day Python programming.

As to the LSP, you aren't in violation, at least the way the principal is normally understood, because you can access the same properties on Lion as on a Feline, and get values of the same type. LSP is generally understood to operate at the level of types, not values.

Comment: My issue with this approach is that now the class' definition depends on its representation. I want to keep the `Animal` classes separate from its "colors" in an attempt to follow Model-View-Controller design. (I believe here the Model and View are getting intertwined)